# This user's avatar doesn't load

Tags: bug, avatar

[image]
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349068/vitalik-brezitsky

```js
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) No profile available for this user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 2018218,
      "fbtrace_id": "ApYja9K7jl3FxHbN7W_y1_-"
   }
}
```

I suppose this is because the Facebook profile of them has been deleted? In anyhow, should it be replaced with a placeholder one?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? I've seen this for years -- I assume it comes from Enhanced Tracking Protection. Try browsing some others where the icon comes from Stack Overflow - they might work. Or try disabling ETP temporarily to see if that reveals the icon.

Comment: I get the same on that profile. I use a VPN routinely too - where does that JSON response come from? Maybe FB or whoever doesn't like serving known VPN IP addresses.

Comment: It looks like an "img" request going to graph.facebook.com is labelled as "Socialtracking" in my FF Network panel. If I turn off ETP then I get the error you do - maybe this is the VPN.

Comment: I see this result in Chrome and Edge too, not just Firefox.

Comment: Can confirm I'm seeing it on Chrome too– it doesn't appear to be a browser-based anti-tracking/ blocking issue, [the GET request to retrieve the image is actually failing for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4fR9.png). Getting a 400 bad request error for some reason? Facebook avatars have always been a bit funky on Stack AFAIK.

Comment: Funnily, when using the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" extension, the [image is not even shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F666x.png) :)

Comment: Can see even when turning off enhanced tracking protection.